# Hive: get minimum value based on year and employee?

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, hiveql

I have a sample table below:

```
+--------------+------------------+-----------+--+
|  orderdate   |     employee     | minprice  |
+--------------+------------------+-----------+--+
| 1992-01-13   | Clerk#943        | 7328.08   |
| 1992-02-21   | Clerk#328        | 33818.37  |
| 1992-02-22   | Clerk#328        | 914.01    |
| 1992-03-03   | Clerk#943        | 10010.11  |
| 1992-03-19   | Clerk#158        | 2712.00   |
| 1992-03-20   | Clerk#328        | 23920.52  |
| 1992-04-05   | Clerk#158        | 919.01    |
| 1993-01-04   | Clerk#943        | 24786.27  |
| 1993-01-29   | Clerk#158        | 11856.13  |
| 1993-01-30   | Clerk#943        | 2712.00   |
| 1993-02-17   | Clerk#328        | 42958.47  |
| 1993-02-25   | Clerk#328        | 2703.00   |
```

How am I able to get the minimum value of an employee based on year? The expected output:

```
+--------------+------------------+-----------+--+
|  orderdate   |     employee     | minprice  |
+--------------+------------------+-----------+--+
| 1992-01-13   | Clerk#943        | 7328.08   |
| 1992-02-22   | Clerk#328        | 914.01    |
| 1992-04-05   | Clerk#158        | 919.01    |
| 1993-01-30   | Clerk#943        | 2712.00   |
| 1993-01-29   | Clerk#158        | 11856.13  |
| 1993-02-25   | Clerk#328        | 2703.00   |
```

What I have at the moment:

```
SELECT o_orderdate, o_employee, min(sales) AS minprice
FROM orders
INNER JOIN sales 
ON o_orderkey = s_orderkey
GROUP BY o_orderdate, o_employee
GROUPING SETS ((o_orderdate, o_employee));
```

The query runs but without filter by year and based on employee. I can't find much documentation on how to do this in Hive and with grouping set.

Appreciate any kind of assistance on this.

Comment: your desired output doesn't support "maximum value of an employee based on year" , for example "Clerk#328 "in 1992  the maximum price for him is 33818.37!
so maybe you should explain what is "maximum value"

Comment: My bad. It should be minimum value. Edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only seem to need a window function, not aggregation:

```
SELECT o_orderdate, o_employee, sale
FROM (SELECT o.o_orderdate, o.o_employee, s.sales,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.o_employee, YEAR(o.order_date) ORDER BY s.sales) as seqnum
      FROM orders o JOIN
           sales s
           ON o.o_orderkey = s.s_orderkey
     ) os
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for the suggested answer. However may I know if based on my above query, is it possible to do the same as yours?

Comment: @datanewbie96 . . . I don't understand your comment.  This answers the question you have asked.  An aggregation query is not the most appropriate approach.

Comment: I am required to do this using aggregation (grouping set specifically) unfortunately.

Comment: I managed to did it. But I will upvote this answer as this is a much better method and also correctly output the desired result. Hope this will help someone else in the future. Thank you.